# How many external displays can I connect to the new iMac (May 2011)

Tags: external-display, displayport, imac, thunderbolt

The new iMac has just been released with two thunderbolt ports.

For those that don't know, thunderbolt comprises of PCI Express and Display Port technology, is also known as 'LightPeak' and is developed by both Apple and Intel.

Thunderbolt ports support display port technology, so they can support any display port display (such as the Apple 27" LED Display").

Since the new iMac has two thunderbolt ports, does this mean that I could connect two external 27" monitors?

Are there any limiting factors besides the amount of available ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly Apple confirmed that to this guy this morning:

http://gigaom.com/apple/new-27-inch-imac-supports-dual-external-display-output/

Answer (score 2):

You can connect two external displays without issue:

http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/03/apple-imac-hands-on-with-dual-30-inch-displays-video/